# Объединять ли предложения и как быть с тире?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире

> Но возвращаясь к тайнам и секретам – к бесконечным попыткам учёных
>   дешифровать сообщения, оставленные нам образованнейшими из
>   представителей своего времени, точнее, возвращаясь к началу разговора
>   – а мы рассуждали про то, что у нас под ногами. Про каменные
>   орнаментальные картины, которые творят братья Космати.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сочинение на тему "Как вы понимаете это предложение?"

**Но возвращаясь к тайнам и секретам  ―  к бесконечным попыткам учёных дешифровать сообщения, оставленные нам образованнейшими из представителей своего времени, ― мы возвращемся к началу разговора, а рассуждали мы про то, что у нас под ногами.** Про каменные орнаментальные картины, которые творят братья Космати.

Comment: Я понял так, что "мы" - это автор с читателями, и он приглашает вернуться вместе с ним к началу разговора, поэтому "верн**ёмся**" (дважды - "грубо" и "точнее"; у автора же вышел двойной деепричастный супероборот в качестве тезиса  - без главного сказуемого).

Comment: Исправила "мы возвращаемся". Так можно оставить? Может быть, вы приведете свой вариант?

Comment: Так нормально. Возможно присоединение второго предложения через двоеточие.

Comment: Боюсь, что это авторская находка, лучше не трогать.

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант:

*Но вернемся к тайнам и секретам – к бесконечным попыткам учёных дешифровать сообщения, оставленные нам образованнейшими из представителей своего времени, точнее, вернемся к началу разговора. А мы рассуждали про то, что у нас под ногами — про каменные орнаментальные картины, которые **сотворили** братья Космати.*

По поводу вренеми глагола: сообщения, **оставленные** нам, — это картины, которые  **сотворили** братья Космати.